# How to display product options on category view?

Tags: magento

I have a grid view of products, each product has a number of children which are configurable products, these have different attributes, in this case 'quantity'.

I'd like to include that information in the product grid view. I've tried copying loads of different bits from the product view page, where it's displayed, but I can't get it to ouput anything.

This is my first forray into Magento, and I know nothing of it's workings beyond the few bits of Zend I've found. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here there is a nice detailed explanation on how to accomplish this:

http://www.catgento.com/adding-configurable-product-options-to-category-list-in-magento/

Comment: That's great, thanks. 'Configurable product options' was what I was missing I'm my search evidently!

Comment: Glad i could help, and nice to see responsive users on here!